# Express, jade layout file rendering body but not rendering head

Tags: node.js, express, pug

My problem is with my jade layout file not rendering correctly.  The body is rendered but the head tags in the produced html are empty.  I have tried to render the layout.jade file separately and it works perfectly.

Here is my layout.jade file

```
!!!
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/style.css')
        script(type='text/javascript', src='javascripts/jquery-1.7.2.js')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='stylesheets/pictogram-button.css')
body
    header(style='padding-bottom:50px;')
        include partials/header
    section(style='min-height:600px;') 
        div!= body
    footer.footer
        include partials/footer
```

And here is my index.jade file

```
.line_h100t
.column_wrap800
    .round_box1_w800
        .list_fl10
            ul.line_h40
                li(style='margin-left:20px;')
                    ul
                        li
                            img(src='/images/icon/whiteWithoutCircle/check.png')
                            img(src='/images/login/loginTxt.png')
                    ul.line_h40t
                        li(style='margin-left:50px;')
                            p 로그인이 필요하신 분은
                            p Oopa Roopa 관리팀으로 문의해 주세요!
                li(style='border-left:1px solid #999; padding:0 0 0 20px;')
                    ul
                        li
                            span.text_yellow ID
                    ul
                        li
                            input.login_input(type='text')
                    ul.line_h35t
                        li
                            span.text_yellow PASSWORD
                    ul
                        li
                            input.login_input(type='password')
                li
                    ul.line_h10t
                        a.button-bevel.transparency(href='#')
                            .line_h35
                                span.lock
                                p(style='width:100px;') LOGIN
```

And here is the function in my express app that renders the index file.

```
    adminLogin : function (req,res) {
    res.render( 'index', {
        title: 'Admin Login',
        pageCategory: 'Admin Login',
        pageName : 'index'
    });
},
```

Thank you in advance for any help you an give me.

Comment: What version of express are you using? In version 3, I believe the notion of layouts was removed.

Comment: I'm using 3.0.0  
My co worker made the jade files.  And as he isn't a native English speaker I'm writing here on his behalf.  Could you please point me toward what I should be doing to get the same effect as using the old style layouts.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In express 3, layouts were removed in favor of template inheritance as explained [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x). The jade [readme](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a11) describes how this works, and an additional example is [here](http://www.devthought.com/code/use-jade-blocks-not-layouts/).

You will need to replace `div!= body` with `block body` (or similar). Then at the top of `index.jade`, you'll want to add `extends layout`. Finally put the contents of `index.jade` under a `block body` (or whatever name you used in `layout.jade`).

Comment: David, how do you send variables to the partial ( `include partials/header` ) in Jade?